# store NSXMLParser to plist file

Tags: iphone

Please guide me how to store NSXMLParser to plist file in iPhone

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to httpget an XML file from the web and store it in an array of dictionaries (plist), so you can write it to file?

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify your question? NSXMLParser is a SAX parser for *reading* XML. If you wish to somehow transcribe some XML content and store it in the iPhone's file system, I would probably use a DOM parser such as TouchXML. As for converting to plist format, I am not aware of a readymade way to do that.